# jquery animate and image resize flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, effects, jquery-animate

i've a problem with a resize effect that i've done in http://www.mcz-scenario.it. When you click on a language, you can see the "background" image transferring into a certain position of the screen.

this is the image:

```
<img id="lago" src="http://www.mcz-scenario.it/images/lago.jpg" height="1070" width="1600" alt="lago" />
```

And this is the "resize" effect

```
$("#lago").animate({
height: 148,
width: 264,
top: endPosition2.top+42,
left: endPosition2.left+350+26}, 4000);
```

Now... I see some flickering running this animation in Firefox. How can i handle this? Is it normal because the image is too large? Help me please :(

THX

Answer (score 0):

Try making the animation faster, say 500 instead of 4000. It seems less disturbing this way even if there is a bit of flicker.

A solution would be to use Flash.

Comment: I cannot decrease time :( and this is a sort of trick... I will not use Flash for many and many reasons :P... 

Sorry

Comment: That's reasonable.
Another idea: try replacing the image with a lower-resolution one right after the user clicked the link, maybe Firefox can scale up faster. (You also need to preload the image to be immediately available when the user clicks)